# Too much work on main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, media-player

I am creating an application that plays back short media file. I want only one media button- when the file is being played it should show the **stop media** icon. As soon as the file is done playing it should revert back to the **play** icon.

Note- `player` is the mediaplayer class with all the relevant methods (prepare; play; stop; pause etc)

I try starting a separate thread in the `onCreate` of the activity like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        final ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.lesson_media_button);
        //BUTTON
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if(media_button == true)
                {
                    media_button = false;
                    player.PlaySound();
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
                }
                else if(media_button == false)
                {
                    media_button = true;
                    player.StopSound(mycontext, audio);
                    button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                }

                while(true)
                {
                    if(player.isPlaying() == false)
                    {
                        media_button = true;
                        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
};
thread.start();
```

The playback is working fine, however I can never stop the file when it is busy playing and the image always shows the **play** icon (never **stop**). When the file is done playing I get **the application may be doing too much work on its main thread** warning.

Can anyone help or suggest a better way to go about this?
Cheers

Comment: That while friend.... That while is not a good thing.

Comment: You can run the while(true) code in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). That would atleast not block the main thread.

Comment: please use service for that.. it will be prove very good for you

Comment: and please dont use infinite loop